# how to create a script to automatically load a specific xorg.conf file?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, bash, xorg.conf

I have two multi-monitor setups   One at work, and one at home.  Every time I come home or go to work, I need to load the NVIDIA GUI and manually set up my multi-monitor configuration.  The NVIDIA GUI allows you to save the xorg.conf.   I therefore would like two bash scripts, one for each setup, that I could run when arriving at home, or at work - so that I wouldn't have to do this step manually each day.  Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Why are you using nvidia app to configure monitors?  Do you really need manual xorg.conf? I think that better idea could be to detect your extra monitor with udev rule and use xrandr to adjust your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to reload lightdm after changing xorg.conf file,
that means all open windows will close, so keep that in mind when running the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /your/xorg/file.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
service lightdm restart
```

Save one version for each /your/xorg/file.conf location and run accordingly.

Edit: Don't forget to run as root!

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom `xserver-command` to start xserver. Default `xserver-command` is available in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf`.

Create script that will execute xserver-command. For example create `/opt/my-xserver-command.sh` with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
X -core
```

Then copy `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf` file to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf` and change `xserver-command=X -core` to `xserver-command=/opt/my-xserver-command.sh`

Now you can pass X your config file. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
X -core -config xorg.conf
```

You can name your config files watever you want. For example `work.conf` and `home.conf`. Now you just need to find something to use to decide what config to use. For example you could detect current time and choose config based on that.